# How to know if an Rx coil is compatible with a wireless Qi charging pad?

Tags: wireless-charging

My goal is to add wireless charging to my project.

There is a list of Rx coil parts available to buy [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/wireless-charging-coils/75).

How do I know if a given coil will be compatible with a Qi charging pad?

Which specs do I need to check for compatibility?

Comment: You go through each one and read the data sheet to match it to your frequency requirements. Some may tell you other things that are relevant such as power handling and, others may not. In other words you need to play detective and narrow down your field to maybe 3 or 4 items then, maybe ask a new question.

Comment: The easiest way is to find one that says it's for Qi. The second easiest way is to pick one that looks about right, and see if it works or not. The hardest way is to research how wireless charging works, how coils work, and how Qi works.